# Trouble with URL containing "+" in CherryPy

Tags: python, url, cherrypy, url-encoding

I have an application in which URLs must be constructed using the plus sign in the URL (because these are names of actual companies).  I'm having some trouble writing links into my HTML that can be correctly received and processed by CherryPy.  I believe the problem is that, in the case of the `+` sign only, both CherryPy and my code are attempting to decode the %2B in the incoming HTML so that it's first converted (correctly) to `+` and then *further* converted (incorrectly) to a space.

For example, consider URLs of the form /:category/:company where the category is `Food and Beverage` and two possible company names are `Eat / Drink / Be Merry` and `Jane+Janet`.

I render these into my HTML with

```
 '/{}/{}'.format(
      urllib.quote_plus(self.category.encode('utf8')),
      urllib.quote_plus(self.company_name.encode('utf8'))
  )
```

Then, in CherryPy, I receive the category and company_name using routes like `/:category/:company_name` and perform the following processing on company_name:

```
def Company(category, company_name):
    print company_name
    company_name = company_name.encode('utf-8')
    print company_name
    company_name = urllib.unquote_plus(company_name)
    print company_name
    company_name = company_name.decode('utf-8')
    print company_name
```

This works correctly for company names without characters subject to URL encoding, and it works for company names with most URL-encoding-required characters (for instance, no problem with `Eat / Drink / Be Merry`).  But, if my original company name had a `+` sign in it, it does not work.  It appears that CherryPy has already done *part* of the decoding for me (replacing `%2B` with `+`) so that when I apply my own decoding, the `+` is replaced with a space.

Here are the results of the four `print` statements for `Eat / Drink / Be Merry`:

```
Eat%20%2F%20Drink%20%2F%20Be%20Merry
Eat%20%2F%20Drink%20%2F%20Be%20Merry
Eat / Drink / Be Merry
Eat / Drink / Be Merry
```

and for `Jane+Janet`:

```
Jane+Janet
Jane+Janet
Jane Janet
Jane Janet
```

My application fails at this point because there is no "Jane Janet" entry in the database to update.

How can I avoid this double-decoding of the `+` sign?

Answer (score 1):

The decoding of the url (percent encoding) is an integral part of the http server, you shouldn't have to do you own `urllib.unquote_plus`.

If you really want to get the *raw* URI, cherrypy has a non-standard `REQUEST_URI` key in the wsgi environment, you can get that with: `cherrypy.request.wsgi_environ['REQUEST_URI']`.

But really, you should just use the params that cherrypy send you directly, the encoding/decoding is part of the transmission of the data with HTTP, it shouldn't concern your application logic.

Comment: But if that's the case, why is the first company *not* decoded when my function receives it?

Comment: Which version of Python and CherryPy are you using? Also, which dispatcher are you using? The default one? `Routes` or `MethodDispatcher`? The `/Eat / Drink `  uri works for me, but maybe I'm not fully understanding your question.

Comment: Python 2.7, CherryPy 3.7.0, using Routes dispatching.  When I receive the parameters in my method, the %2B has already been decoded for me but %20 and %2F have not.

Comment: @LarryLustig AFAIU you just want `%2B` to be represented as `+` when it reaches a handler. It looks Iike `unquote_plus` happens after it gets urldecoded in your case (but should happen before that). 
Could you please reproduce this with the latest version of CherryPy. It might have been fixed.

Comment: P.S. This might happen in `routes` package, which is separate from CherryPy, so this should be checked as well. Maybe you just need to upgrade it.